# weird animation after UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, xcode

My rootViewController is based on UITabViewController
and one of the tab view, that i initialize a UINavigationController to push a view.

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addStoreViewController];

[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

then i push another view in the addStoreViewController
here's the code:

```
PictureViewController *pictureViewController = [[PictureViewController alloc] init];    
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pictureViewController animated:YES];
```

finally, i want to use UIImagePickerController in pictureViewController
here is the code from my camera button:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.delegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

The level of my view controller:

[UITabViewController] > [UINavigationController] -> [AddStoreViewController] -> [PictureViewController] > [UIImagePickerViewController]

Everything works fine but there's one thing weird. After presenting UIImagePickerViewController, other view will be affected with strage animation.
The whole UI in the view will display with an extra animation, like UITextField, UINavigationBar, UIButtons...everything you see on the view. Even when you typing and the text will display with weird animation!
is there anything wrong with my code? I googled this issue for a long time but can't find out.
could anyone help me? thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops i found the answer and im such an idiot...
it was caused by my UIView Animation.
I forgot to insert this `[UIView commitAnimations]` in end of my animation.

Comment: Thank u so much for posting this issue!
I had the same problem, my uiimagepicker elements were flickering at touches.
I missed commitAnimations in one of my child views.
I googled so much and u are finally the only one I found.
Hope my comment helps others while googling.